# Python and charset

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with python charset and German characters. I'm trying to obtain a string from the database using mysqldb trying this:

```
array=result.fetch_row()[0]
```

If I print the array I get all values and my string 'f\xfcr' <-- this is what I need.

But if I print `array[stringlocation]` I get `'f�r'` that represent 66 fc 72 (why isn't this unicode any more?)

If I write this to a file: `'fÃŒr'` or hex 66 C3 BC 72

I think that isn't a problem with mysqldb. I can't get the chars as I need.

Note: I'm using set names latin1. If I use utf8 I will get doubles: `f\xc3\xbcr`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The quick answer: Read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html), and return to the ways of UTF-8. :-)

Comment: Well... i tried some encode/decode/unicode functions and i still don't get how to write readable characters

Comment: How are you writing to the file? keep in mind that `'f\xfcr'` isn't unicode to begin with; it's a string of bytes.

Comment: open("./out.sql", "wb") can't see any difference with W or WB as the char is being converted

Comment: btw i need to write same 'f\xfcr' (correct latin1)

Answer (score 1):

If `'f\xfcr'` is what's coming back from the database, and is identical to what you need to write to a file, the only problem is what is being displayed when you print it. For that you need to do a translation.

```
>>> print 'f\xfcr'.decode('latin1')
für
```

This works because the `print` command will automatically translate the Unicode produced by `decode` back into the character set used by your display.